# java Switch default for the rest of indexes not used in the cases

Tags: java, switch-statement

I need to use the Switch's default to assign values to the array elements with indexes that were not used in the Cases.

Example:

```
public class sample {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] animalArray = new String[5];

    String animal = "Dog";

    switch(animal){             
    case "Dog":
        //The position 0 is found using some calculation
        animalArray[0] = "Dog"; 
        break;

    case "Cat": 
        ////The position 3 is found using some calculation
        animalArray[3] = "Cat";
        break;      
    default:

        //How do I get the value of x to be 1,2,4

        animalArray[x] = "Undefined";
    }           
    }    
}
```

Now I need some way to tell that the indexes that were not already used in the case statement should be used here in the default.

How do I implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefill the array before you use it.

```
String[] animalArray = new String[5];
Arrays.fill(anumalArray, "undefined");
```

Then you can set any known values.